# Loop through textboxes inserting values textboxes not in array

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if it is possible to loop through all the textboxes on a page and insert a value into each one starting with the number 1 and going up by +1.
There are over 150 textboxes on this page and they are not in an array and I would not like to rename them one by one.. :-(

Thanks for any help....

Comment: "rename" or "set a value", what should it be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
var j = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].type == "text") {
    input[i].value = ++j;
  }
}
```

Comment: @matt Yes, it seems. It isn't. ;)

Answer (score 1):

***[Try this out:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/Rz3br/)***

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function(index) {

    $(this).val(index);

})
```

---

Per the request of some, for completeness' sake, the above requires the JavaScript library, jQuery.  You can reference it like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
```

If you aren't using `<!DOCTYPE html>` you can include the `type="text/javascript"` attribute.

Comment: That does work but the OP didn't mention they are using jQuery

Comment: @Matt - True, but you never know. =)

Comment: It needs jquery, and he doesn't seem to mention it

Comment: @Chuck - Yes ... I know that, and Matt already commented on that before you.  He didn't NOT mention it either. =D  It's always nice to see all possibilities from the standpoint of the asker, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Add <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js'></script> for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

```
function FillTextBoxes()
{
    var tbs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var valCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0 ; i < tbs.length ; i++)
    {
        if (tbs[i].type == "text")
        {
            tbs[i].value = ++valCount;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = FillTextBoxes;
```

Comment: There was a bug in it. Updated after reading Tomalak's answer.

Comment: ok, but this one works also.. :-)  thanks so much guys for all of ur help